# Very slow solve and problem when solving in a nested for loop

Tags: equation-solving

I am using a nested for loop to solve a system of equation for {a, ga} for 2 varying parameters: here it's rm and sig.

```
 params[ss_, mm_] := {c -> 0.05, mu -> 1, bo -> 10, k -> 0.01,  sig -> ss, eps -> 1, rm -> mm}
 b[a_] := bo a/(1 + a);
 rS[ga_] :=  rm/(1 + c ga);  
 rI[ga_] := eps rS[ga] ;
 getres[aa_, gg_] := Solve[{0 == (rS[gg] x + rI[gg] y) (1 - k (x + y)) - (mu + (b[aa] y)) x + gg y,
                            0 == b[aa] x y - (mu + aa + gg ) y}, {x, y}][[4]]

 par[a_, ga_] :=  Block[{}, res = getres[a, ga]; Seq = x /. res; Ieq = y /. res; 
 b'[a] - b[a]/(mu + a + ga + sig b[a] Ieq)]

  hit[a_, ga_] :=  Block[{}, res = getres[a, ga]; Seq = x /. res; Ieq = y /. res; 
  rS'[ga]  (1 - k (Seq + Ieq)) + (rI'[ga] (1 - k (Seq + Ieq)) b[a] Ieq)/(mu + a + ga) + (rS[ga] (1 - k (Seq + Ieq)) - mu)/(mu + a + ga)]

 getsol[sig_, rm_] :=  Solve[{0 == par[a, ga], 0 == hit[a, ga]} //. params[sig, rm], {a, ga}]
```

When I write the parameter sig and rm that I want by hand, it is slow but ok:

```
    getsol[0, 1] 

(*{{a -> -0.274696 + 6.20784 I, 
 ga -> -39.4619 - 3.41054 I}, {a -> -0.274696 - 6.20784 I, 
 ga -> -39.4619 + 3.41054 I}, {a -> -7.28491*10^-10, 
 ga -> -1.}, {a -> 7.28491*10^-10, ga -> -1.}, {a -> 0.0358705, 
 ga -> -0.998713}, {a -> 0.453121, ga -> -0.794681}}*)
```

but if I created a nested for loop to vary those parameter, it does not solve anything (I know that for some parameter values there is no solution, but for some values, 1 or 2 exist, so I should find something !)

```
    For [i = 0, i < 0.3, 0.1, 
           For[j = 0, j < 0.3, 0.1, sig = i; rm = j;
                  getsol[sig, rm]
              ]
         ]
```

It gives me the error:
    (*Part::partw: Part 4 of {{x->((1+a) (a+ga+mu))/(a bo),y->-(((1+a) mu (a+ga+mu))/(a bo (a+mu)))},{x->0,y->0}} does not exist. >>*)

So I know that I'm taking the 4th solution of 'getres' (positive and real), but why doesn't it work here? I've been adding Clear[sig, rm] everywhere but it does not solve the problem !
Any kind of help to improve the time to process and to understand why it does not solve in my for loop is highly welcome !!!

Comment: The first term evaluated is `getfol[0,0]` and this also gives the same error. So the loop is a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Bill S, `getsol[0,0]` fails.  In fact, `getsol[sig,0]` appears to fail for any value of `sig`.  I suggest you try

```
For[i = 0, i < 0.3, i = i + 0.1, 
 For[j = .1, j < 0.3, j = j + 0.1, sig = i; rm = j; 
  Print[sig, "  ", rm, "  ", getsol[sig, rm]]]]
```

which excludes `rm = 0`.  Note also that the third argument of the outer `For` has been changed from `0.1` to `i = i + 0.1`, and similarly for the inner `For`.  Otherwise, the loops compute the same expression repeatedly.  Additionally,  `Print` has been added in order to display the results.

As you remarked, the calculations are very slow for some parameters.

Comment: Awesome !! It works !! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Unnecessary use of `SetDelayed` rather than `Set` causes repetitive recalculations and slows everything down. Use of `Simplify` with some of the interim calculations also improves performance.

```
params[ss_, mm_] = {c -> 0.05, mu -> 1, bo -> 10, k -> 0.01, sig -> ss, 
   eps -> 1, rm -> mm};

b[a_] = bo a/(1 + a);

rS[ga_] = rm/(1 + c ga);

rI[ga_] = eps rS[ga];

getres[aa_, gg_] = 
  Solve[{0 == (rS[gg] x + rI[gg] y) (1 - k (x + y)) - (mu + (b[aa] y)) x + 
        gg y, 0 == b[aa] x y - (mu + aa + gg) y}, {x, y}][[4]] // Simplify;

par[a_, ga_] = Block[{},
   res = getres[a, ga]; Seq = x /. res; Ieq = y /. res;
   b'[a] - b[a]/(mu + a + ga + sig b[a] Ieq)];

hit[a_, ga_] = Block[{},
    res = getres[a, ga]; Seq = x /. res; Ieq = y /. res;
    rS'[ga] (1 - k (Seq + Ieq)) + (rI'[ga] (1 - k (Seq + Ieq)) b[a] Ieq)/(mu +
         a + ga) + (rS[ga] (1 - k (Seq + Ieq)) - mu)/(mu + a + ga)] // 
   Simplify;

getsol[sig_, rm_] := 
 Solve[{0 == par[a, ga], 0 == hit[a, ga]} /. params[sig, rm], {a, ga}]

Table[{
  "sig = " <> ToString[sig],
  "rm = " <> ToString[rm],
  getsol[sig, rm]},
 {sig, 0, 0.3, 0.1},
 {rm, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1}]
```

> {{{"sig = 0.",     "rm = 0.1", {{a -> -0.0250166 + 5.01892 I, 
>        ga -> -26.1889 - 0.251113 I}, {a -> -0.0250166 - 5.01892 I, 
>        ga -> -26.1889 + 0.251113 I}, {a -> -0.901488, 
>        ga -> -0.187319}}}, {"sig = 0.",     "rm = 0.2", {{a -> -0.0514703 + 5.26649 I, 
>        ga -> -28.7332 - 0.542135 I}, {a -> -0.0514703 - 5.26649 I, 
>        ga -> -28.7332 + 0.542135 I}, {a -> -0.801944, 
>        ga -> -0.356886}}}, {"sig = 0.",     "rm = 0.3", {{a -> -0.078452 + 5.4485 I, 
>        ga -> -30.68 - 0.854892 I}, {a -> -0.078452 - 5.4485 I, 
>        ga -> -30.68 + 0.854892 I}, {a -> -0.701347, 
>        ga -> -0.508113}}}}, {{"sig = 0.1",     "rm = 0.1", {{a -> -0.0916848 + 5.01913 I, 
>        ga -> -26.2134 - 0.256992 I}, {a -> -0.0916848 - 5.01913 I, 
>        ga -> -26.2134 + 0.256992 I}, {a -> -0.84974 + 0.0825409 I, 
>        ga -> -9.93676 - 15.6267 I}, {a -> -0.84974 - 0.0825409 I, 
>        ga -> -9.93676 + 15.6267 I}}}, {"sig = 0.1",     "rm = 0.2", {{a -> -0.125137 + 5.26702 I, 
>        ga -> -28.7739 - 0.551852 I}, {a -> -0.125137 - 5.26702 I, 
>        ga -> -28.7739 + 0.551852 I}, {a -> -0.799511 + 0.0930563 I, 
>        ga -> -0.654073 - 16.856 I}, {a -> -0.799511 - 0.0930563 I, 
>        ga -> -0.654073 + 16.856 I}}}, {"sig = 0.1",     "rm = 0.3", {{a -> -0.157543 + 5.44958 I, 
>        ga -> -30.7361 - 0.867882 I}, {a -> -0.157543 - 5.44958 I, 
>        ga -> -30.7361 + 0.867882 I}, {a -> -0.748851 + 0.0735576 I, 
>        ga -> 7.93714 - 12.7668 I}, {a -> -0.748851 - 0.0735576 I, 
>        ga -> 7.93714 + 12.7668 I}}}}, {{"sig = 0.2",     "rm = 0.1", {{a -> -0.158886 + 5.02191 I, 
>        ga -> -26.2384 - 0.261619 I}, {a -> -0.158886 - 5.02191 I, 
>        ga -> -26.2384 + 0.261619 I}}}, {"sig = 0.2",     "rm = 0.2", {{a -> -0.199348 + 5.27057 I, 
>        ga -> -28.8155 - 0.559327 I}, {a -> -0.199348 - 5.27057 I, 
>        ga -> -28.8155 + 0.559327 I}}}, {"sig = 0.2",     "rm = 0.3", {{a -> -0.237147 + 5.45404 I, 
>        ga -> -30.7934 - 0.877603 I}, {a -> -0.237147 - 5.45404 I, 
>        ga -> -30.7934 + 0.877603 I}, {a -> -0.646544 + 0.164275 I, 
>        ga -> -5.3496 - 14.9584 I}, {a -> -0.646544 - 0.164275 I, 
>        ga -> -5.3496 + 14.9584 I}}}}, {{"sig = 0.3",     "rm = 0.1", {{a -> -0.226353 + 5.02736 I, 
>        ga -> -26.2639 - 0.264911 I}, {a -> -0.226353 - 5.02736 I, 
>        ga -> -26.2639 + 0.264911 I}}}, {"sig = 0.3",     "rm = 0.2", {{a -> -0.273768 + 5.27722 I, 
>        ga -> -28.8578 - 0.564416 I}, {a -> -0.273768 - 5.27722 I, 
>        ga -> -28.8578 + 0.564416 I}}}, {"sig = 0.3",     "rm = 0.3", {{a -> -0.316875 + 5.46196 I, 
>        ga -> -30.8516 - 0.88386 I}, {a -> -0.316875 - 5.46196 I, 
>        ga -> -30.8516 + 0.88386 I}}}}}

Comment: This is a huge improvement to my code and time process ! I always thought SetDelayed was IMPROVING my time, not slowing it down ! Now what took 400s takes 18s ! Thank you !